# fscanf C - determining letter instead number

Tags: c, io

I am loading matrix from file and here comes the question, how to treat if there will be fault in loading file if there will be letter instead of number? I am especially asking - how to determine, that I loaded letter?

Thx

Comment: You can format what you try to read with fscanf(), can you give an example of how you try to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input read by `fscanf()` does not match the expected type (as determined by the conversion specifier), this will be reported by the return value of `fscanf()` (which is equal to the number of coversion specifiers *successfully* read).

```
int x;   
if ( fscanf( file, "%d", &x ) != 1 )
{
    // input was not a number
}
```

More generally speaking, the whole `scanf()` family of functions is primarily aimed at reading whitespace-separated, trivial data. Usually it is more easy and reliable to read in a complete line (using `fgets()`), and then doing the parsing internally. (`strtol()` and `strtod()` can be of help here, but `strtok()` should be used with care, especially in a multithreaded environment.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't `fscanf()`.

`fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

In case of error, you still have the original data for error recovery (or to show the user, or whatever)

And always check the return value of the `scanf` family of functions.

```
if (fscanf(stdin, "%d", &var) != 1) { /* oops */ }
```

---

```
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) { /* oops */ }
if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &var) != 1) { /* oops */ }
```